# SharePoint Online - Copy SharePoint List Items from multiple Subsites to a main site

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio, sub-site, remote-event-receiver

I have a SharePoint site "Test", in which i have a Custom List "Test1 List". I also have a few Sub sites for the Test site and each subsite has a custom list associated with it (For example, Test2 List for a subsite1, Test3 List for another subsite2 etc..). The columns of Test1 List, Test2 List, Test3 List are all the same.

So when ever a new item is created in Test2 List or Test3 List (Lists of multiple Subsites), i want to copy the item to Test1 List (Main site). This is like a cross site copy.

For example - If a new item is created in Test2 List(Subsite1), this should be copied on to Test1 List(Main site). Later if a new item is created in Test3 List(Subsite2), this should also be added to Test1 List(Main site) following the previously added item (In our case it should be added below the Test2 List item).

I know there is no Workflow action available to copy List item from Subsite to Main site.

Even if there is no exact solution, please throw some comments. Anything is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to use REST.  [This](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) explains how to call the REST api from a workflow.  One thing to note, you can use JSON Light.  So instead of using `application/json; odata=verbose`, you can set it to `application/json; odata=nometadata`, and you won't have to worry about setting the `__metadata` field.